# FYI - Self promotion

Tags: support, self-answer, abuse

> #### May I promote products I am affiliated with here?
>
> The community generally frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam, so be careful. Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product, so be it. However, *you must disclose your affiliation with the product in your answers.*
>
> Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product, you're clearly here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; [contact our ad sales team](https://stackoverflow.com/about/contact) for details.
>
> <sub>**[Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limit-to-self-promotion-in-answers/59302#59302)**</sub>

Answer (score 12):

Also, I vote that asking your own question for the sole purpose of answering it with the product you are affiliated with is **not cool** - even though in that case the answer can be 100% relevant to the question, and the question itself may be otherwise valid.